# What are the skills need to perform Mobile testing

Tags: manual-testing, mobile

Am a fresher and I want to learn testing on mobile platforms. Please help me out in understanding the required skills I need to be well versed in or acquire to perform testing on mobile platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some skills you might want to acquire,

1. Critical thinking
2. Good communication
3. Domain knowledge
4. Understanding of mobile platforms
5. Understanding of mobile networks and how data transfer occurs.
6. Familiarity with different platforms, OS and browsers
7. Awesome reporting skills
8. Focus
9. Curiosity
10. And a hell lot more

Happy Testing :)